# Сохранение запроса Sql без создания data frame

Tags: python, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать запрос sql в python без создания DataFrame и как это лучше реализовать. Задача состоит в том, чтобы скрипт сработал автоматом (ОС Windows) и не создавал при этом временную таблицу, так как данные очень объемные, желательно сразу сохранял результат в папку.

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import csv

# Подключение к БД
def connectToServer():
    try:
        userpwd = '****'
        con = cx_Oracle.connect('схема',userpwd,'сервер',encoding='UTF-8')
        print ("Connection successful")
        with con.cursor() as curs:
            curs.execute('')
        print("Command successful")
        return con
    except(Exception,cx_Oracle.IntegrityError) as error:
        print (error)

# Выполняем SQL запрос

def readValues(con):
    sql = """
select -- запрос

"""
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)
    return df
   

# Создаем DataFrame
con = connectToServer()
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = readValues(con)
print (df)


# Сохраняем данные в csv
df.to_csv(r'С:\\path\file.csv', index=False)

# Закрываем подключение
#cursor.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: Ну читайте результат запроса и пишите построчно в файл. Без конкретного кода вопрос слишком абстрактный. Ответ - можно.

Comment: `DataFrame` это у pandas, что ли? Используйте модуль `sqlite3` для запросов в `sqlite`

Comment: база Oracle с применял Notebook

Comment: код который применяю сейчас, но когда данных много все зависает. Если есть другие варианты как это реализовать без временных таблиц и без применения pandas, так как основные манипуляции с файлом делаю в других По

Comment: Ну вот можете не использовать `Pandas`, а просто построчно читать результаты запроса и писать их в файл.